# add column priority to mysql natural language search when matching 2 columns

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am trying to make use of mysql natural language full text search.I have two columns against which the query will be compared.However, i need one of the columns to have higher precedence than the other so that words that occur in high precedence column should should have higher relevance score.I have gone through the mysql documentation once.I cant find anything. Is this possible with Mysql? or is there any other means to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my thoughts:

- create two fulltext indexes;
- query table twice with for the first column and second one. Union results. The result should be ordered by weight of "similarity" which will be different for both columns.
- limit resulting data set.